# have numpy.arange repeat a given amount of times

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get `np.arange()` to count up to a given number a given amount of times so, it can return an array like this: `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: You can just do `[1, 2, 3] * 4`. If you really want to use `np.arange`, you can do `np.tile(np.arange(1, 4),  4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) it:

```py
>>> np.tile(np.arange(1, 4), 4)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

Or as j1-lee said, repeat at the list level:

```py
>>> np.array(list(range(1, 4)) * 4)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```